# The data parased from the website ended up with being an empty data (bs4, python, lxml)

Tags: beautifulsoup, lxml

Hello Stackoverflow folks,

I have had a very hardtime with parsing information from a website 
using Beautifulsoup and lxml.

I tried to bring the address data from "https://www1.nyc.gov/events/events-filter.html#page-1" website.

As far as I googled,

it says I need to 
1. find the specific class for the information through "inspection" of the webpage.
2. need to write a code like `g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "event-data-detail"})`

So I wrote my code as below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www1.nyc.gov/events/events-filter.html#page-1"
r=requests.get("https://www1.nyc.gov/events/events-filter.html#page-1")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)


links = soup.find_all("a")

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "event-data-detail"})

print(g_data)
```

and it shows the error message

> Warning (from warnings module):   File
>   "C:/Users/jotna/Desktop/Portfolio/1.py", line 7
>       soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content) UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for
>   this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run
>   this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it
>   may use a different parser and behave differently.
>
> The code that caused this warning is on line 7 of the file
>   C:/Users/jotna/Desktop/Portfolio/1.py. To get rid of this warning,
>   pass the additional argument 'features="lxml"' to the BeautifulSoup
>   constructor.

So I fixed the code as below. (Cause a posting in stackoverflow suggested to add lxml code at the end)

```
import lxml
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www1.nyc.gov/events/events-filter.html#page-1"
r=requests.get("https://www1.nyc.gov/events/events-filter.html#page-1")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)


links = soup.find_all("a")

for link in links:
   if "http" in link.get("href"):
       print ("<a href='%s'>%s</a>" %(link.get("href"), link.text))

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"span class": "address"})

print(g_data)
```

However it only shows empty bracket 
[]

How can actually bring the address data from the website?

For your information, I uploaded the screen shot of the webpage source as well.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px2hY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use their json api instead of bs4, see the code below.

```
import requests
count = 0
for i in range(185):
    count+=1
    link = 'https://www1.nyc.gov/calendar/api/json/search.htm?&sort=DATE&pageNumber='+str(count)
    req = requests.get(link)
    for i in req.json()['items']:
        address = (i['address'])
        print 'Address:', address
```

Output

```
Address: Mulberry Street, Little Italy, New York
Address: Various locations Citywide
Address:  SECOND AVENUE between EAST   32 STREET and EAST   33 STREET  Manhattan
Address:  FIRST AVENUE between EAST   92 STREET and EAST   93 STREET  Manhattan
Address:  CARROLL STREET between SMITH STREET and COURT STREET  Brooklyn
Address:  BROADWAY between WEST  114 STREET and WEST  116 STREET  Manhattan
Address:  CORTELYOU ROAD between RUGBY ROAD and ARGYLE ROAD  Brooklyn
Address:  QUEENS BOULEVARD between 70 AVENUE and 69 ROAD  Queens
Address:  79 STREET between NORTHERN BOULEVARD and 34 AVENUE  Queens
Address:  PRINCE STREET between MOTT STREET and MULBERRY STREET  Manhattan
Address:  BUSHWICK AVENUE between NOLL STREET and ARION PLACE  Brooklyn
Address: Alley Pond Park Adventure Center
Address: Atlantic Avenue between 4th Avenue and Hicks Street
Address: Alexander von Humboldt statue - Central Park West and 77th Street
Address:  SEVENTH AVENUE between WEST  110 STREET and WEST  111 STREET  Manhattan
Address: Wave Hill House - West 249th Street and Independence Avenue
Address: Broadway between Liberty Street and Rector Street
Address: Anibal Aviles Playground
Address: Myrtle Avenue between Fresh Pond Road and Wyckoff Avenue
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. Havn't thought of using Json.